# How to get to the elements on a page control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm working with Delphi 7.

Suppose I have a page control on my form. This page control has two or three tabs. Each tab has a few other controls like a label, edit etc. on it. How to get, for example, to an edit's text property in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still directly access the TEdit

```
Edit1.Text := 'My Edit box on a Tab';
```

Comment: Thank you for a good reminder. That's very easy to forget. Because in FoxPro, from what I remember, in order to get access to controls within other controls, you have to start with the parent control. In Delphi this is not the case however.

Comment: Well technically that is correct in Delphi also, however you use the owner rather than the parent. The TEdit's owner is the TForm it is on.  You could refer to it as Form1.Edit1 but since you are writing code in Form1 already you don't need this prefix.

Answer (score 11):

Iterate across the controls of the tabsheet using its `ControlCount` and `Controls` properties.

```
for i := 0 to TabSheet.ControlCount-1 do
begin
  if TabSheet.Controls[i] is TEdit then
    ShowMessage(TEdit(TabSheet.Controls[i]).Text);
end;
```

This will iterate over all immediate children of the tabsheet. If you need to iterate deeper into the children of the children and so on then you want a recursive solution.

If you want to search in each tabsheet then you need to iterate over them too.

```
for i := 0 to PageControl.PageCount-1 do
  TabSheet := PageControl.Pages[i];
  for j := 0 to TabSheet.ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    if TabSheet.Controls[j] is TEdit then
      ShowMessage(TEdit(TabSheet.Controls[j]).Text);
  end;
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question that you asked. The other answer, that you accepted, is an answer to a different question.

Comment: I disagree David, as Mikhail has pointed out he didn't realise he could simple access his TEdit in the usual way, your answer is very good but an answer to a different question. :)

Comment: @TobyAllen No. I answered the question that was asked, "How to get to the elements on a page control?" You gave the solution to the actual problem. You answered the question that should have been asked. However, that question would never have been asked because the solution is trivial. That question would have been, "If I have an edit control, `Edit1` say, how do I access that control's `Text` property?"